# Orientdb Super Slow Query Performance

Tags: orientdb

I have tried several things for far too long and I am struggling with the **performance** of **Orientdb Community edition 3.0.0RC2**. The current query takes anywhere between **60-100 seconds** to run but I would think it should take milliseconds since it is **only 27k records** to scan with an index setup. The server (*normal server config*) is setup on my personal computer which has **8gb** of memory and **HDD**.

Query to run: `select count(*) from ClassA where InitialInvestment = 2000`

- Class A (26,844 records):
- InitialInvestment | DOUBLE
- LeveragedEtfPercent | DOUBLE
- MarketPercent | DOUBLE
- OverallReturn | DOUBLE
- PercentCash | DOUBLE
- QuarterlyAdd | DOUBLE
- StartDate | Date
- Results | EmbeddedList -> Class DataRecord (Each Result list has about 9-10k items)

Index (all have been "rebuilt"):

- NotUnique SBTREE on InitialInvestment
- NotUnique SBTREE on MarketPercent and LeveragedEtfPercent
- Unique SBTree on MarketPercent, LeveragedEtfPercent, and StartDate

Class DataRecord (strangely, 0 records show in Schema view in Studio but the items in the embedded list show a class of "DataRecord" - will ask about this 
later). This class only has three DOUBLE fields and one Date field. Doubt this class is affecting the query given I am not trying to query it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use a Release Candidate when v3.0 GA is out by more than 1 month. Right now you can get the v3.0.2 GA is out.
2. Could you please execute the explain? `explain select...` so you can check if any indexes were used. Please post the result by updating your question.
3. It looks like your records are too fat by embedding 9-10 thousands of DataRecord objects. Much lighter creating the DataRecord objects outside the main record and link to them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Lvca! I will give these suggestions a shot and report back. Would you suggest a LinkedList or using edges?

Comment: You could use a LinkedList if you don't need bidirectional edges, but once you have edges you can go back and forth between vertices that it's nice. Also, if you need to use Gremlin or Graph algorithms, they work only with edges.